# Excel converting multiple tables to longform data

Tags: excel

I have a data set which I need to convert to longform, so I'd be able to use it in a data analysis program (R). The format is standardised for each table so I'm wondering if there is a way to have excel to transpose the data for me. 
Thanks in advance for the help.

Data set
[image: Data set]

Longform
[image: Longform]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to do this regularly for a lot of data, writing a macro to loop through everything would be best. A manual workaround that is still quicker for a lot of data is to create a set of formulas that converts all data from one point at one person's place into 8 lines of longform data. Then by changing a reference you can re-use these formulas for every point at every person's place:

Your first 4 columns are manual: Location, Point, Quarter, Type. They have fixed values for every 8 rows. Enter them manually for one data point, they'll all get copied later.

Then have a 5th working column that records the location of an anchor point for every set of data at a point at a persons place. For this example, I'm assuming you have a "NW" value in cell B3 on a sheet called "Data". In your 5th table column, in first row only (Cell E2) put in the text "Data!B3" without an equal sign.

The remaining columns for all 8 rows all refer to this anchor point using the OFFSET and INDIRECT functions. For each column in your data for the first 8 rows, refer to each value in the data set based on their relative position from the anchor point:

The first data column is the NW Shrub Distance value, which is offset by 1 rows and 1 columns:
    =OFFSET(INDIRECT(E2),1,1)

The second data column is NW Shrub Height, which is offset by 1 row and 2 columns:
    =OFFSET(INDIRECT(E2),1,2)

Continue through the rest of the columns on that row. Then go to the next row in your table. The first data column there is the NE Shrub Distance, which is offset by 7 rows and 1 column from the anchor NW cell:
    =OFFSET(INDIRECT(E2),7,1)

Then the second data column in the 2nd row is the NE Shrub Height, which is offset by 7 rows and 2 columns from the anchor NW cell:
    =OFFSET(INDIRECT(E2),7,2)

Prepare these formulas for all columns for all 8 rows. It will take a little while, but after you're done, you can then just copy the entire chunk and paste it below the first chunk. Update the one anchor value for the whole chunk from Data!B3 to the NW location in the next data chunk, eg Data!H3, and all formulas will now pull the values from all cells relative to new anchor point.

Repeat this for every data chunk and you'll have it in longform fairly quickly.

Comment: Thank you for that, it took me a little while to get my head around it but deffently faster than manually doing all the data.
Screenshot of final layout https://imgur.com/a/bkyT9